# bind9 on ubuntu not pingible from bind9 server (but pingible from other machines) (noob)

Tags: ubuntu, bind, local-area-network

As in question. Is it possible to ping on bind9 server machine to dns its serving?

I want to do:

## ping hpc.lan

```
PING hpc.lan (12.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from M.hpc.lan (12.1.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
64 bytes from M.hpc.lan (12.1.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms
64 bytes from M.hpc.lan (12.1.1.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.175 ms
```

And its working besides server machine with bind9.

What could be the reason. I mess up config of bind, or should state it in hosts? I can ping to hostnames in my lan... Im noob in networking, sit like one day this lan + dhcp + dns, so please show some compassion :D

When I do dig from other machines i have:

```
dig hpc.lan

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> hpc.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50994
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hpc.lan.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hpc.lan.        604800  IN  A   12.1.1.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
hpc.lan.        604800  IN  NS  M.hpc.lan.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
M.hpc.lan.      604800  IN  A   12.1.1.1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 01 10:49:52 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

Also from windows machine:

```
nslookup hpc.lan

Server: gateway.hpc.lan
Address: 12.1.1.1

Name: hpc.lan
Address: 12.1.1.1
```

or reverse

```
nslookup 12.1.1.1
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

1.1.1.12.in-addr.arpa   name = M.hpc.lan.
1.1.1.12.in-addr.arpa   name = gateway.hpc.lan.
```

But from bind9 server machine dig gives:

```
dig hpc.lan


; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> hpc.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 6784
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hpc.lan.           IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86398   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018063002 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 01 10:58:31 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

and for nslookup

```
nslookup hpc.lan
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find hpc.lan: NXDOMAIN

a@M:~$ nslookup 12.1.1.1
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 1.1.1.12.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

a@M:~$ nslookup 12.1.1.50
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 50.1.1.12.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

a@M:~$ nslookup 12.1.1.90
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 90.1.1.12.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

or reverse one

```
nslookup 12.1.1.1
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 1.1.1.12.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Clearly it dont see dns of my lan, then go in sky...

My config on bind9 server is as follows:

## sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
acl "trusted" {
    12.1.1.0/24; # ns1
    //192.168.1.0/24;
    localhost;
    localnets;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    listen-on { trusted; };
    //allow-transfer { none; };

    //allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-query { trusted; };
    allow-query-cache { any; };

    forwarders {
        12.1.1.1;
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };

    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

## sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

// send ads to black hole
include "/etc/bind/ad-blacklist";


// our local zone
zone "hpc.lan" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.hpc.lan";
};


// reverse for .hpc domain
zone "1.1.12.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    notify yes;
    file "/etc/bind/db.hpc.lan.r";
};
```

## sudo nano /etc/bind/db.hpc.lan

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA M.hpc.lan. root.hpc.lan. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
hpc.lan.    IN  NS  M.hpc.lan.
hpc.lan.    IN  A   12.1.1.1
;@      IN  NS  localhost.
;@      IN  A   127.0.0.1
;@      IN  AAAA    ::1
M       IN  A   12.1.1.1
N0      IN  A   12.1.1.55
L0      IN  A   12.1.1.90
www     IN  CNAME   hpc.lan.
gateway     IN  A   192.168.1.1
```

## sudo nano /etc/hpc/db.hpc.lan.r

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA M.hpc.lan. root.hpc.lan. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  M.
1   IN  PTR gateway.hpc.lan.
1   IN  PTR M.hpc.lan.
55  IN  PTR N0.hpc.lan.
90  IN  PTR L0.hpc.lan.
```

## sudo nano /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   M #VN278AA-UUW-m9860sc
12.1.1.1    M #VN278AA-UUW-m9860sc-enp1s10
192.168.1.106   MS #VN278AA-UUW-m9860sc-enp0s10
```

## sudo nano /etc/hostname

```
M
```

## sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# external
auto enp0s10
iface enp0s10 inet dhcp
#iface enp0s10 inet static
#   address 192.168.1.106
#   gateway 192.168.1.1
#   mtu 1500
#   metric 1000
#   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4

# internal 
auto enp1s10
iface enp1s10 inet static
    address 12.1.1.1
    network 12.1.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.106
    broadcast 12.1.0.255
    mtu 7152
    dns-nameservers 12.1.1.1
    metric 100
```

## sudo nano  /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named

```
... 
  /var/log/bind/** rw,
  /var/log/bind/ rw,

}
```

## sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name "hpc.lan";
option domain-name-servers 12.1.1.1;

default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 172800;

authoritative;

log-facility local7;

# wan network, we dont provide service here
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
}

# lan network we provide service for
subnet 12.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 12.1.1.50 12.1.1.99;
    option routers 12.1.1.1;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 12.1.0.255;
}

host N0 {
    hardware ethernet 00:25:11:4f:9d:92;
    fixed-address 12.1.1.55;
}

host L0 {
    hardware ethernet f0:de:f1:5b:d3:da;
    fixed-address 12.1.1.90;
}
```

## Edit

by they way nslookup works dns and reverse dns works, but problem is that on server machine, lookup is skipping 12.1.1.1 and go directly to 8.8.8.8

may there be some problem with forwarding here?

my iptables are

## cat /etc/iptables.conf

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jul  2 01:22:43 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [406:28839]
:INPUT ACCEPT [180:15615]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2024:169350]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [66:3986]
-A POSTROUTING -o enp0s10 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o enp1s10 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jul  2 01:22:43 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jul  2 01:22:43 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1211066:4289490990]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [750206:1045506458]
-A FORWARD -i enp1s10 -o enp0s10 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp0s10 -o enp1s10 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jul  2 01:22:43 2018
```

Comment: BIND doesn't answer to ICMP ping. You should test DNS using DNS tools.

Comment: On your server, the DNS clients (like the dig command or ping) query 8.8.8.8 (Google) as seen in your results. Google won't resolve your private DNS. So it's probably about [`resolv.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/resolv.conf.5.en.html) and alike. And by the way, if 12.1.1.1 is not a public IP (which belongs to AT&T) it shouldn't have been used. See [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) [1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918)

Comment: I know but why other stations in my lan can ping to hpc.lan, but station with bind9 server cant ping to it and is redirected to 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Do not use a fake TLD like `.lan` to name your resources, you risk getting into a nasty clash like people who used `.dev` discovered. Register a domain name and use a subdomain of it to name your resources.

Comment: ok so lets say i have domain: mydomain.ddns.net they I need to simply use this domain in place of hpc.lan everywhere above, or there is more to do?

Comment: in my config i changed 12.1.x.x to 10.10.x.x as @A.B suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the best way was to do like that (i dont know how bad it is, no experience, but it seem working)

## sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
GNU nano 2.5.3         File: /etc/network/interfaces                          

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# external
# auto enp0s10
# iface enp0s10 inet dhcp


auto enp0s10
iface enp0s10 inet static
        address 192.168.1.106
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        mtu 1500
        metric 100
        up ethtool -s enp0s10 wol g
        dns-nameservers 12.1.1.1
        ifdown enp0s10 --ignore-errors
        ifup enp0s10 --ignore-errors


# internal
allow-hotplug enp1s10
iface enp1s10 inet static
        address 12.1.1.1
        network 12.1.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.106
        broadcast 12.1.0.255
        mtu 7152
        dns-nameservers 12.1.1.1
        metric 0
        up ethtool -s enp1s10 wol g
        ifdown enp1s10 --ignore-errors
        ifup enp1s10 --ignore-errors
```

then i dont have problems with `sudo service network restart`, before it was some error (even at reboot):

> File exist...
>   Interface enp1s10 is up...
>   Failed to raise interface enp1s10...

Then update resolvconf

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

That will become

## cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 12.1.1.1
```

also note that it may be configured in dhcp mode like

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


#external eth0
allow-hotplug enp0s10
iface enp0s10 inet dhcp
#allow-hotplug enp0s10
#iface enp0s10 inet static
#       address 192.168.1.106
#       gateway 192.168.1.1
        mtu 1500
        metric 100
#       dns-nameservers 10.10.1.1
        up ethtool -s enp0s10 wol g
        up ifdown enp0s10 --ignore-errors
        up ifup enp0s10 --ignore-errors
        pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.rules

#internal eth1
allow-hotplug enp1s10
iface enp1s10 inet static
        address 10.10.1.1
        network 10.10.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.106
        broadcast 10.10.0.255
        mtu 7152
        metric 0
        dns-nameservers 10.10.1.1
        up ethtool -s enp1s10 wol g
        up ifdown enp1s10 --ignore-errors
        up ifup enp1s10 --ignore-errors
        up resolvconf -u
```

But then

```
resolvconf -u
```

will result with

## cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
root@M:/home/a# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
search zyxel.com
```

so it will end up badly! then sky interface has to be static (why?)...

Answer (score 2):

The resolver on the BIND9 server is apparently configured to use the Google name server 8.8.8.8. You need to change that to use its local BIND9 instance instead. In file `/etc/resolv.conf`, change the line

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

to

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: i would like to avoid changes in /etc/resolv.conf, bcos they will die at reboot <cry>

Comment: That means you have something installed that manages the resolver settings for you. In that case you have to find out what that is, and tell it to use 127.0.0.1 instead of 8.8.8.8 as its resolving server. Perhaps you can remember (or have documented - yes, I'm dreaming, but this *is* ServerFault after all) where you entered 8.8.8.8 when you set up that server, and change it to 127.0.0.1 there.

Comment: Perhaps one of the answers to this AskUbuntu question will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot

Comment: i put it in forwarders,    forwarders {
        12.1.1.1;
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };

Comment: That can't be the only place. The forwarders directive tells your local BIND9 server where to ask for external domains. It doesn't tell your local resolver to circumvent your local BIND9 server and ask 8.8.8.8 directly.

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
nameserver 12.1.1.1
search zyxel.com
damn

Comment: how to find what is editing my /etc/resolv.conf, i dont use gui in ubuntu and uninstalled network-manager

Comment: It's written on top of the /etc/resolv.conf you pasted: "generated by resolvconf".